# day, month, year in dropdownlist

Tags: c#

Hey,
I got a problem, my brain is wrecking, when i try to figure it out.

My problem is, that i need to get day and month in dropdownlist, just like i have got my year.

I show how i got the year in dropdown.

Then i want a solution to do the same, just for days and months

**I only need the code behind.**

#### Code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList_year" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

#### Code Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        for(int yr = year-3; yr > year - 115; yr--)
        {
            DropDownList_year.Items.Add(new ListItem(yr.ToString()));
        }

        for (int day = 1; day < 32; day++)
        {
            DropDownList_dag.Items.Add(new ListItem(day.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

I could do like this?

```
for (int day = 1; day < 32; day++)
        {
            DropDownList_dag.Items.Add(new ListItem(day.ToString()));
        }
```

But, in February there isn't 31 days, but 28, so how to do that? without change it every month?

Comment: Surely the Month dropdown is just going to be a list of numbers from 1 to 12? The Day dropdown could be easy too, i.e. 1 to 31, but it will be trickier if you want to be accurate because then you will have to modify the list depending on what values for year and month are selected.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `calendar` control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Why complicate yourself with the dropdown list for calendar? Like George said, it's easier and simpler to use Calendar control to get the year, month & day.

Comment: Well, like if you are editing your profile, then you dont scroll throw an calendar, but instead you are choosing from a dropdownlist, and i would like to do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [MSDN - DateTime.DaysInMonth()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as a basis to find the number of days in a given month for a given year.

The days will be correct for the Gregorian calendar, you'll have to include some events to make sure you get the correct number of days in February to account for leap years.

Edit:  Very quick and dirty code.  Add the contents of each collection to your drop down lists.  Keep in mind that February's number of days will only be correct for this year.  I would handle an event based on the year the user selected to get the correct number of days.

```
    private static void GetDates()
    {
        var lstYears = new List<int>();

        int iYearNow = DateTime.Now.Year;

        for (int year = iYearNow; year > iYearNow - 115; year--)
        {
            lstYears.Add(year);
        }

        var lstMonthWdays = new List<int[]>();

        for (int month = 1; month < 13; month++)
        {
            lstMonthWdays.Add(new int[] { month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(iYearNow, month) });
        }
    }
```

I wouldn't recommend using this exact code in production but it should give you somewhere to start.

Comment: Seems like its some of what i would use.
But, i need it to appear in the dropdownlist.

Comment: @Zeuthenjr check my edit, gave some sample code for you to build on.

Comment: i get an error while i try do this:
DropDownList_month.Items.Add(new ListItem(month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(iYearNow, month).ToString()));
I dont know what im doing wrong?